# Python Container Issue referring back to main()

Tags: python, containers

I am trying to read a simple text file and get the output in basic line format. I have a parent class and a child class. I start out by instantiating the child class, which should be inheriting the data structure from the parent class (that's all it contains). When parsing the input file, the child class should be entering the lines into the list established upon child class instantiating line by line. I cannot figure out how to get the output called from `main()`

I have tried regex to parse groups into the list but it doesn't seem to make a difference or help. I also tried calling the output function at the end of the add() function. When I check the output function neither the list or the object is defined.

input, separated by single spaces

```
    E031 HR+ 301d
    E005 HR+ 263d
    E036 HR+ 415d
    E043 HR+ 68d
    E003 HR+ 133d
    E044 HR+ 323d
    E047 HR+ 117d
    E037 HER2+ 14d
    E048 TNBC 27d
    E049 TNBC 148d
    E046 TNBC 269d
    E015 TNBC 0d
```

main.py

```
    import data

    def main():
        #declare ObservationSet object
        entry = data.ObservationSet()
        entry.loadFile("input.txt")

        entry.output()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

data.py

```
    #class dfn & constructor

    class Observation:
        def __init__(self, patientNum = None, marker = None, timeLapse = None):
            self.patientNum = patientNum
            self.marker = marker
            self.timeLapse = timeLapse




    #class dfn & constructor
    class ObservationSet():

        def __init__(self, observations=None):
            self.observations = observations

            #establish list for multiple observations
            if self.observations is None:
                self.observations = list()

                #isa list here -- print(type(self.observations))

        #load file to process lines function

        def loadFile(self, fileName):
            for line in open(fileName):
                #line = line.rstrip()    
                #add here to Observation object            
            for patient in line:
                observation = Observation(patient)
                self.add(observation)

        #append to observations list next line of observations
        def add(self, observation):
            self.observations.append(observation)

        def output(self):
           #no  idea
```

What I'd really like to see is something like this using .format()

Patient Number: E031     BioMarker: HR+ Time Lapse Between Molecular and Clinical Relapse: 301 days

*****EDIT
Firstly, I hope the indentation is clearer
Secondly, I was wrong. Container is correct and not inheritance. I'll go back and see if I can fix it. I removed the obvious inherit lines thus far. But I am unsure on the code to make ObsSet the container for Obs.

*****EDIT 2
I tried this edit:

```
    for patient in line:
            observation = Observation(patient)
            self.add(observation)
```

and this:

```
    def output(self):
        for obs in self.observations:
        print(obs)
```

In the output function, obs is an object, not the data itself. And, if I take the reference self.observations, I get a global name not defined error. That is, obs is a data.Observation object.

Comment: `observations` *is not defined* in `output`. You've created an *instance variable* `self.observations` which is probably what you meant?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation? It's not quite clear which blocks of code belong where.

Comment: As an aside, your inheritance here doesn't make a lot of sense. It seems like `ObservationSet` is supposed to be a *container* of `Observation` objects. Generally, that isn't a use-case for inheritance, that is, containers *have* instances of the items they contain, they *are not* instances of the items they contain.

Comment: `ObservationSet` should not inherit from `Observation` - inheritance implies an is-a relationship that simply is not true here (and the fact that the two classes have entirely separate attribute names should be an indication of this).

Comment: you probably just want: `for obs in self.observations: print(obs)`?